# Group by ids with padding in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I given a 1D tensor of ids `idxs` and a 1D tensor of values `values` I want to create a padded 2D padded tensor where each row correspond to the id. For example:

```
idxs = tf.constant([1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4])
values = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
output = fn(values, idxs, -1) # = [ [1, 8, 3], [4,5,-1], [6,-1,-1], [7,2,9]]
```

In the above examples fn would be the function I want to write. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a working solution for fn. It's not a very elegant or efficient solution however.

```
def get_ith_occurance(ith_occurance, all_positions, values, default_value):
  # Get the ith occurrence in all_positions if it exists 
  return  tf.cond(
      f.size(all_positions)>ith_occurance,
      lambda:values[all_positions[ith_occurance]], 
      lambda:default_value)

def get_padded_group_row(id_value, ids, col_size, values, default_value):
  # the positions of occurrences of id_value in ids
  all_id_positions = tf.cast(tf.reshape(
      tf.where(tf.equal(ids, id_value)), [-1]), tf.int32)
  column_idxs = tf.range(col_size)
  return tf.map_fn(lambda col_num: get_ith_occurance(col_num, 
                                                     all_id_positions, 
                                                     values, 
                                                     default_value), column_idxs)


def fn(idxs, values, default_value):
  ids, id_positions = tf.unique(idxs)
  col_size = tf.cast(tf.reduce_max(tf.unsorted_segment_sum(
      tf.ones(tf.size(id_positions)),
      id_positions, 
      num_segments=tf.size(ids))), tf.int32)
  return tf.map_fn(lambda id_value: get_padded_group_row(id_value, 
                                                         idxs, 
                                                         col_size, 
                                                         values, 
                                                         default_value), ids)          



idxs = tf.constant([1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4])
values = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
output = fn(idxs, values, -1)
```